# SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW to get USB power data always get "8"

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to use the `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW` function to grab the USB device power data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertyw

My question is result is `8` , i don't no why

**Update-2022/6/4**

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w
import uuid

SetupAPI = ct.WinDLL('SetupAPI')

ULONG_PTR = w.WPARAM


class HDEVINFO(w.HANDLE):
    pass

class GUID(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('Data1', ct.c_ulong),
                ('Data2', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data3', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data4', ct.c_ubyte * 8))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"GUID('{self}')"

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{{{self.Data1:08x}-{self.Data2:04x}-{self.Data3:04x}-'
                f'{bytes(self.Data4[:2]).hex()}-{bytes(self.Data4[2:]).hex()}}}')

    def __init__(self,guid=None):
        if guid is not None:
            data = uuid.UUID(guid)
            self.Data1 = data.time_low
            self.Data2 = data.time_mid
            self.Data3 = data.time_hi_version
            self.Data4[0] = data.clock_seq_hi_variant
            self.Data4[1] = data.clock_seq_low
            self.Data4[2:] = data.node.to_bytes(6,'big')

PGUID = ct.POINTER(GUID)

GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = GUID('{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}')

class SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('cbSize', w.DWORD), 
                ('ClassGuid', GUID), 
                ('DevInst', w.DWORD), 
                ('Reserved', ULONG_PTR))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={self.ClassGuid}, DevInst={self.DevInst})'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cbSize = ct.sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)

ENUM = ct.c_int 
POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM = 7

class _SYSTEM_POWER_STATE(ENUM):
    PowerSystemUnspecified = 0
    PowerSystemWorking = 1
    PowerSystemSleeping1 = 2
    PowerSystemSleeping2 = 3
    PowerSystemSleeping3 = 4
    PowerSystemHibernate = 5
    PowerSystemShutdown = 6
    PowerSystemMaximum = 7

SYSTEM_POWER_STATE = _SYSTEM_POWER_STATE
PSYSTEM_POWER_STATE = ct.POINTER(_SYSTEM_POWER_STATE)
   
class _DEVICE_POWER_STATE(ENUM):
    PowerDeviceUnspecified = 0
    PowerDeviceD0 = 1
    PowerDeviceD1 = 2
    PowerDeviceD2 = 3
    PowerDeviceD3 = 4
    PowerDeviceMaximum = 5   

DEVICE_POWER_STATE = _DEVICE_POWER_STATE
    
PDCAP_D0_SUPPORTED = 0x00000001
PDCAP_D1_SUPPORTED = 0x00000002
PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED = 0x00000004
PDCAP_D3_SUPPORTED = 0x00000008
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D0_SUPPORTED = 0x00000010
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D1_SUPPORTED = 0x00000020
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D2_SUPPORTED = 0x00000040
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D3_SUPPORTED = 0x00000080
PDCAP_WARM_EJECT_SUPPORTED = 0x00000100
        

class CM_Power_Data_s(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('PD_Size', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_MostRecentPowerState', DEVICE_POWER_STATE),
        ('PD_Capabilities', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D1Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D2Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D3Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_PowerStateMapping', DEVICE_POWER_STATE * 
                                 POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM),   
        ('PD_DeepestSystemWake', SYSTEM_POWER_STATE),
        ]

PSP_DEVINFO_DATA = ct.POINTER(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes = PGUID, w.PWCHAR, w.HWND, w.DWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype = HDEVINFO

SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.argtypes = HDEVINFO, w.DWORD, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA
SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.restype = w.BOOL 

SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.argtypes = HDEVINFO,
SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.restype = w.BOOL

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA.argtypes = HDEVINFO, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA, 
w.DWORD, w.PDWORD, w.PBYTE, w.DWORD, w.PDWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA.restype = w.BOOL

DIGCF_DEFAULT         =  0x00000001  
DIGCF_PRESENT         =  0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES      =  0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE         =  0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE =  0x00000010


ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
Enumerator = None
hwndParent = None
Flags = DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT

devinfo = SP_DEVINFO_DATA()


PropertyRegDataType = None
PropertyBuffer = None
size = 0
RequiredSize = None


hDevInfo = SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(ClassGuid, Enumerator, hwndParent, Flags)

DeviceInfoSet = hDevInfo
DeviceInfoData = ct.byref(devinfo)    
SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA   =  0x0000001E  # Device Power Data     
PropertyRegDataType = None
#PropertyBuffer = None
PropertyBufferSize = 0
RequiredSize = w.DWORD()

try: 
    MemberIndex = 0
    while SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, MemberIndex, 
     ct.byref(devinfo)):
    print(devinfo)
    SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
                                         hDevInfo,
                                         ct.byref(devinfo),
                                         SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA,
                                         PropertyRegDataType,
                                         None,
                                         PropertyBufferSize,
                                         ct.byref(RequiredSize))                                                          
    
    print(RequiredSize.value)
    PropertyBuffer = (w.BYTE * RequiredSize.value)()
    if not SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
                                         hDevInfo,
                                         ct.byref(devinfo),
                                         SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA,
                                         PropertyRegDataType,
                                         PropertyBuffer, 
                                         ct.sizeof(PropertyBuffer),
                                         ct.byref(RequiredSize)):
        break
    
    result = ct.cast(PropertyBuffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))[0]
    print(result)
              
    MemberIndex += 1       
    
finally:
    SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo)
```

Comment: Stick to the W versions of functions.  They work better with Python 3.  I recommend implementing your query in C first so you understand the order of operations and then porting that.  Just throwing the code at the end of the last example I posted after the `hDevInfo` has been destroyed is definitely not going to work.

Comment: I updated the code can you help to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyBuffer` must be cast to a `CM_Power_Data_s` structure and the members examined.  Your code is casting to a `wchar_t*` and accessing only the first character.

Use the following to cast correctly and access the structure.  `.contents` is like dereferencing the pointer:

```py
result = ct.cast(PropertyBuffer,ct.POINTER(CM_Power_Data_s)).contents
print(result.PD_Size, result.PD_Capabilities) # etc.
```

Alternatively, define a `__repr__` for the CM_POWER_DATA class and then `print(result)`:

```py
class CM_Power_Data_s(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('PD_Size', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_MostRecentPowerState', DEVICE_POWER_STATE),
        ('PD_Capabilities', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D1Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D2Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D3Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_PowerStateMapping', DEVICE_POWER_STATE * 
                                 POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM),   
        ('PD_DeepestSystemWake', SYSTEM_POWER_STATE),
        ]

    # Format how you want the structure to display
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'CM_Power_Data_s({self.PD_Size}, {self.PD_MostRecentPowerState.value}, {self.PD_Capabilities:#x})'
```